# Need help to get an insert statement in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I would need to insert the non existing values to a Table.

- Table name `BarcodeSubgroup` (single column table)
- Column (`nvarchar`)

Sample data in the table

```
ProductSubGroupID
-----------------
F11WD
F77AH
G36CN
G37HJ
H11AA
H11AD
```

Now I need to insert the non existing values in the table.

Values want to be checked and inserted.

```
H11AA
H11AD
G78DE
G76DK
G41JA
B45JC
```

Query written

```
insert into BarcodeSubgroup 
   select 
       productsubgroupid 
   where 
       not exists ('G78DE', 'G76DK', 'G41JA',
                   'B45JC', 'H11AA', 'H11AD')
```

Now it should insert only the 4 non existing values.

Comment: what is your problem exactly?

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with `select . . . not exists`:

```
insert into BarcodeSubgroup(productsubgroupid)
    select productsubgroupid 
    from (values ('G78DE'), ('G76DK'), ('G41JA'), ('B45JC'), ('H11AA'), ('H11AD') ) v(productsubgroupid)
    where not exists (select 1
                      from BarcodeSubgroup bs
                      where bs.productsubgroupid = v.productsubgroupid
                     );
```

Comment: I am still getting the below error   Msg 8158, Level 16, State 1, Line 33
'V' has more columns than were specified in the column list.